# Queries Regarding OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0

A simple scenario I have a typical architecture a client,authorization server(OAuth Server) and Resource Server.Client gets token from authorization server with client_credentials and sends token to resource server and it serves the request.So if I have 2 API's either the logged in user can access all or none based on valid or invalid token.
Is there a mechanism to grant access to 1 API ? The question is can token be API specific like it give access to 1 API and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

The `scope` mechanism can be used to differentiate between permissions that are associated with the access token. E.g. there could be a scope for API A and one for API B. The client could ask for one of those scopes or both and the token would be valid for respectively calling both APIs or just one of them.

See also: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3 which doesn't say much about the semantics of `scope` but in practice a scope is almost always associated with a (set of) permission(s).

Comment: Whatever you are saying is absolutely correct with respect to client permission.The question is wrt. User.Say a client has both scope . This allows all the user to access both resources trying to access via same client.what if I want User A to access API A and User B both.

Comment: You should use a grant type that involves the user rather than client_credentials or use a client_id  per user